# read file to String array and show each record

Tags: java, arrays, file

My code should read file and store each line(each record) into a String array.

My txt file is it:

```
FName Lname Number
second secondsecond 22
thired thithird 33
fourth fourfourr 44
fifth fiffif 55
```

but, when i run my code, my program do not display first character of each line!
Show like this:

```
econd secondsecond 22
hired thithird 33
ourth fourfourr 44
ifth fiffif 55
```

My code:

```
public class ReadfileIntoArray {

String[] columns=new String[]  {"FName","Lname","Number"};
String[] data=new String[100];

public void read() throws IOException{
FileReader fr=new FileReader("D:\\AllUserRecords.txt");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;  

while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

    for(int i=0;i<=br.read();i++){
        data[i]=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
    }  
br.close();
System.out.println("Data length: "+data.length);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    ReadfileIntoArray rfta=new ReadfileIntoArray();
    rfta.read();
}
}
```

And i want see the data length:5 (because i have five line), But i see 100 !

(I want this information for abstract table model)

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code modified:

```
public class ReadfileIntoArray {

    String[] columns = new String[] { "FName", "Lname", "Number" };
    String[] data = new String[100];

    public void read() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\AllUserRecords.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;

        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            data[i] = line;
            System.out.println(data[i]);
            i++;
        }
        br.close();
        // This is for resize the data array (and data.length reflect new size)
        String[] dataNew = new String[i];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataNew, 0, i);
        data = dataNew;
        System.out.println("Data length: " + data.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReadfileIntoArray rfta = new ReadfileIntoArray();
        rfta.read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have declared array size as 100 on the second line. So how you have basically two options, if count of the lines in file won't change, then declare the size of the array as 5. If it is going to vary, then I suggest you to use for example [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
//in the while loop
data.add(br.readLine());
```

Comment: The lines are going to more

Comment: Then use an ArrayList as I suggested, it's a collection which means that you don't have to care about it's size, it will change dynamicaly as you need

Comment: Can i use ArrayList in table model constructor? How?

Comment: Use `.toArray()` to get a String array once you're done reading. (i.e. Use `data = (String[]) myList.toArray();` after the loop.)

Comment: @user1945649: what is table model constructor?You can use it wherever you want, just create a list and then use its method add to new strings - just as I wrote above

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` array will always be the size of 100, because when you instance it (`String[] data = new String[100]`) creates a blank array with 100 indexes. Instead of using a `String[]`, you could use a `List<String>`

Comment: Is list that Arraylist? Or it is different?

Comment: Yes.  List<String> is an interface. It is good practice to use a variable of this type. It can point at an ArrayList<String> object.

Comment: Can i use ArrayList in table model constructor? How?

Answer (score 0):

`br.read()` is reading one character from the start of each line, leaving `br.readLine()` to read the rest.

This inner loop makes little sense.

```
for(int i=0;i<=br.read();i++){
    data[i] = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(data[i]);
}
```

This should be all you need. If you don't want the first line, add an additional call to `br.readLine()` before the loop.

```
int i = 0;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    data[i] = line;
    System.out.println(line);
    i++;
}
```

You should also try using a dynamicaly-sized data structure to store the strings (e.g. `ArrayList<String>`) if you don't know how many lines to expect. You can then use `myList.size()` to get the line count.

```
List myList = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    myLine.add(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}  

System.out.println(myList.size());

//Retrieve the data as a String[].
String[] data = (String[]) myList.toArray();
```

Comment: Can i use ArrayList in table model constructor?

Comment: I don't believe so, but List does have `.toArray(...)`. Collect your Strings in the ArrayList, then use `.toArray(...)` to get a String[] when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the loop that reads the lines, use the String method `split` to process each line.  Do not draw from the reader, as it moves the file pointer forward as it reads.  You can split on whitespace by using

```
String [] parts = stringName.split("\\s");
```

Then you have complete access to all three items in each line.

Answer (score 0):

why so complicat?
below is my solution, for reference.

```
String line;  
int cnt;

cnt = 0;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    cnt++;
}

br.close();
System.out.println("Data length: "+cnt);
```